# InOrder traversing in a generic Binary Tree Java

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, inorder

I have to code a tree with a method which prints all values in the tree in ascending order. So I choose the traversal Algorithm In order. It also must be recursive. I have searched for 2 days in the internet to solve this problem. After this i wrote this method.

My Input is : 20,19,13,15,7,28,4,23,9
so the Output must be: 4,7,9,13,15,19,20,23,28
but my output is: 4 9 7 15 13 19 20 28 23

why?

Here is the part of code you need

```java
    class Tree<V extends Comparable<V>> {
    
        class TreeNode {
            V val;
            TreeNode left, right;
    
            TreeNode(V v) {
                val = v;
            }
        }

    TreeNode root; 

       void insert (V val) {
            if (root == null)
                root = new TreeNode(val);
            else
                insert(root, val);
            // TODO implement this method
        }
    
        private void insert (TreeNode parent, V val) {
            TreeNode t = root;
            int cmp = val.compareTo(t.val);
            if (cmp >= 0) {
                if (parent.left == null)
                    parent.left = new TreeNode(val);
                else
                    insert(parent.left, val);
            }
            else {
                if (parent.right == null)
                    parent.right = new TreeNode(val);
                else
                    insert(parent.right, val);
            }
        }

    // - to print all values in the tree in ascending order
        void printNodesAll () {
            printNodesAll(root);
        }
    
        private void printNodesAll (TreeNode node){
            if (node == null)
                return;
            else {
                printNodesAll(node.right);
                System.out.printf("%s ", node.val);
                printNodesAll(node.left);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Tree <Integer> names = new Tree <>();
            names.insert(20);
            names.insert(19);
            names.insert(13);
            names.insert(15);
            names.insert(7);
            names.insert(9);
            names.insert(4);
            names.insert(28);
            names.insert(23);
    
            names.printNodesAll();
    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `insert` function. specifically the line:

```
TreeNode t = root;
int cmp = val.compareTo(t.val);
```

This means that all of your inserts will be evaluated against the root node, not the parent node of the recursive call. by changing these lines to just

```
int cmp = val.compareTo(parent.val);
```

the comparison will be valid